# Convert one Multidimensional JSON array to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I have the following input object

```
{
    "id": 1,
        "isLeaf": false,
            "name": "New rule",
                "pid": 0,
                    "dragDisabled": true,
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": "new1",
                                "value": "data1",
                                "then": false,
                                "type": "set",
                                "forEach": false,
                                "pid": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "new2",
                                "value": "data2",
                                "then": true,
                                "type": "if",
                                "forEach": false,
                                "pid": 1,
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "id": "new3",
                                        "type": "Then",
                                        "enableElse": true,
                                        "pid": "new2",
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                                "id": "new5",
                                                "value": "data3",
                                                "then": false,
                                                "type": "fuzzy_search",
                                                "forEach": false,
                                                "pid": "new3"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": "new4",
                                        "type": "Else",
                                        "enableElse": true,
                                        "pid": "new2",
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                                "id": "new6",
                                                "value": "data4",
                                                "then": false,
                                                "type": "return",
                                                "forEach": false,
                                                "pid": "new4"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
}
```

I need to convert it into the following json

```
[
    {
        "id": "new1",
        "condition": "data1"
    },
    {
        "id": "new2",
        "condition": "data2",
        "then": [{
            "id": "new5",
            "condition": "data3"
        }],
        "else": [{
            "id": "new6",
            "condition": "data4"
        }]
    }
]
```

I have to recursively iterate through all existing inner child array of the input json array to formulate the output.
Following is the partially implemented code for the functionality.

```
ruleJSONFormatter = (request, parentItem, innerJSON) => {
    try {
        var outerObject = request;
        if (outerObject.children && outerObject.children.length) {
            var innerArray = outerObject.children;
            // second iteration with inner children
            innerArray.forEach((innerItem, index) => {
                let parentObj = {};
                let recursiveObj = {}; let thenArray = [];
                recursiveObj['condition'] = innerItem.value && innerItem.value != undefined ? innerItem.value.formatedData : {};
                recursiveObj['type'] = innerItem.type;
                recursiveObj['id'] = innerItem.id;
                recursiveObj['pid'] = innerItem.pid;
                if (innerItem.children && innerItem.children != undefined && innerItem.children.length) {
                    switch (innerItem.type) {
                        case 'if':
                            recursiveObj['then'] = [];
                            recursiveObj['else'] = [];
                    }
                    if (Object.keys(parentObj).length == 0) {
                        parentObj = recursiveObj;
                    } else {
                    }
                    ruleJSONFormatter(innerItem, parentItem, parentObj)
                } else {
                    if (Object.keys(parentObj).length == 0)
                        responseArray.push(innerJSON);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log("No Values Inside the Formated Data ")
        }
        console.log("output-----------");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(responseArray));
        return responseArray
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('((((((((((((((((((((((((((', error)
    }
}
```

final output array has a condition key which binds the value key from the input json and 'then' key which contains the multiple successive inner children array which is the success condition for type 'if' object. similar is the case for 'else' key in output

I find it hard to recursively call the same function to generate the desired output. the problem arises when there are deep nesting in the children array.Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could edit to format the indenting of the input/output into something a little more readable?

Comment: @MarkMeyer I have made the suggested changes to both datasets. maybe you could take a look